# Can't get components displayed with react-scroll navigation

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-scroll to navigate to different sections on the same page. I've been following a tutorial and everything works but I have dummy text in each section and now I don't know how to change the content to my components. Basically I have three components and I want one to be displayed in each section of my web page but I can't get it working. 
I don't want `title`, `subtitle`, `dark` etc in each section. Instead I want to just put my whole component in that section.

Can someone show me how I would put one of my components in each section (there are three components and three sections)? Is this possible or do I have to re-structure my website so that the content is separated in to different parts like shown in section.js?

Important: The part which I don't understand is how to link up my content in Section.js:

Section.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Section({ title, subtitle, dark, id }) {
  return (
    <div className={"section" + (dark ? " section-dark" : "")}>
      <div className="section-content" id={id}>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{subtitle}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Section
          title="section1"
          subtitle={dummyText}
          id="section1"
        />
        <Section
          title="section2"
          subtitle={dummyText}
          dark={false}
          id="section2"
        />
        <Section
          title="section3"
          subtitle={dummyText}
          dark={true}
          id="section3"
        />
      </div>
```

Navbar.js

```
 <nav className="nav" id="navbar">
        <div className="nav-content">
          <button
            className="nav-logo"
            alt="Logo"
            onClick={this.scrollToTop}
          >Top</button>
          <ul className="nav-items">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                activeClass="active"
                to="section1"
                spy={true}
                smooth={true}
                offset={-70}
                duration={500}
              >
                About
              </Link>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to pass a component to your Section Component instead of these params?

```
{ title, subtitle, dark, id }
```

if this is a case, you can use `children`

```
export default function Section({ children }) {
    return (
        <div>
          {children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

then you can put your component here:

```
<div className="App">
    <Section>
        // your component
    </Section>
</div>
```

Comment: for more info https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment